# Return a copy of incomplete type in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have just found out that this code is legal in header files (at least) in VS 2010

```
class AClass; //forward declaration of AClass (incomplete type);
class UseAClass
{
   public: 
      AClass returnAClass(); //return a copy of incomplete type - AClass ???
}
```

Could someone explain me why can I write this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is allowed because the knowledge of the size of `AClass` is not required by the compiler at the point of *declaration* of the function which returns `AClass`.  However, if you attempt to provide a *definition* of the function there (or make a member of type `AClass` in the class `UseAClass`), then `sizeof(AClass)` is required by the compiler, and thus you need to include the header file in which `AClass` is defined. You can also do this:

```
void acceptAClass(AClass obj); //only the declaration, NO DEFINITION!
```

Note that this technique is often used to break the cyclic dependencies of headers, as this doesn't require some headers to be included in `.h` file : just forward declaration is enough. And in the `.cpp` file, you include the header and provide the definitions.

Comment: Is this behavior defined in C++ standards? According to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration), I'm not allowed to return an incomplete type

edited: nvm, I've seen the differences

Comment: @Name: Sorry, [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration) doesn't say that. It is **not** allowed **when you provide the definition**. It is allowed when you provide only the *declaration*. Read the post again. :-)